# Why can't i pass this pointer to other function as an argument in go?

Tags: go, pointers

I'm just learning GO (with javascript background)

So, i use this [excelize](https://github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize) package to create excel document using go.

Here's my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize"
)

func main() {
    f := excelize.NewFile()

    create(f)
}

func create(f *int) {
    fmt.Println(&f)
}
```

It's giving me an error `cannot use f (type *excelize.File) as type *int in argument to create`

Is there anything wrong with my code ?

I'm pretty bad with this whole pointer things, but i have to learn go in 2 weeks.

I also put my code in this [GO playground](https://play.golang.org/p/aqcSmkGL8pv) site just in case someone want to test it.

Comment: This has literally nothing to do with pointers.

Comment: i'm sorry, even if that isn't, that means i have no idea what cause the error @Volker

Answer (score 2):

`create()` expects a value of type `*int`, that is, a pointer to `int`. `f` in `main()` is of type `*excelize.File`, that is, a pointer to `excelize.File`.

The value you pass to `create()` must be [assignable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to the type of the parameter, and `*excelize.File` is not assignable to `*int`. Details: [Spec: Calls](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls).

For example, a value of type `*int` is assignable to the param of `create()`, so this is valid:

```
var i int
create(&i) // i is of type int, so &i is of type *int
```

Or this:

```
j := new(int) // j is of type *int
create(j)
```

If you want your `create()` function to accept a value of any type, use the empty interface: `interface{}`

```
func create(f interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(f)
}
```

Then passing `f` from `main()` (or any other value) will be valid:

```
f := excelize.NewFile()
create(f)
```

Comment: So in short, i can't pass f to the create function ? is there any other way in order to pass f to create function ?

Comment: @BeingShame Yes, you can't.